# Passing an array copy to a function expecting a reference

Tags: php, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I have a loop of the following kind:

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    $attrs = array('NAME' => $key);
    myproc ($attrs);
    ......
}
```

Where in `myproc` the first parameter is defined by reference:

```
function myproc (& attrs) {  .... }
```

`myproc` adds the passed value to some structure.

The trouble with this is that at loop end, all the arrays added to the generated structure contains the same value, the last value extracted from the loop.

I tried also something like this :

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    $attrs = array('NAME' => $key);
    $copy = $attrs;
    myproc ($copy);
    ......
}
```

but the result is the same.  I'not allowed to modify the procedure. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is; using another variable like in your example or assigning the value again after the function call should give you an un-modified value of the array. What results do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: the trouble is not the modified value of the array just after the call (in which case i could reassign the value) the problem is that the myproc procedure adds the array to a list of objects.
After the loop is terminated, if i inspect this list, every array in the list has the same value. I Il'' try to make a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment below your question, it seems that the problem is that you are passing a reference and this reference gets updated in the loop, leading to updates in the object you are generating in your function.

To avoid this, you need to unset the variable after the function call so that the link between the value in your object and the referenced variable is broken:

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    $attrs = array('NAME' => $key);
    myproc ($attrs);
    // unset the variable so that newer values of it will have no effect 
    // on the object generated in `myproc`
    unset($attrs);
    ......
}
```

Also see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php).

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. I thought the statement  
    $attrs = array('NAME' => $key);
would create a new object every time and that the (pointer ? address ? reference ?) to it was assigned to the variable, $attrs. (like, e,g, in c#) 
I see that the memory handling in Php is much more complex than I thougth.

Comment: @Maurizio No, with that statement - after the first iteration - you are assigning a new value to an existing variable, not defining a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

foreach(['red','pink','green'] as $colour) {
    $attrs = ['colour' => $colour];
    if(colourToAction($attrs)) {
        $results[] = $attrs;
    }
}

var_export($results);

function colourToAction(&$attrs) {
$actions = ['red'=>'stop','amber'=>'wait', 'green' => 'go'];
if(isset($attrs['colour']) && isset($actions[$attrs['colour']])){
    $attrs['action'] = $actions[$attrs['colour']];
    return true;
}
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'colour' => 'red',
    'action' => 'stop',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'colour' => 'green',
    'action' => 'go',
  ),
)
```

Comment: You might not want to wrap the results assignment in the if block.  As here it only stores the result on success of the function.  Or you might want to copy the attrs array to a temp variable to then compare with attrs after the function call to see if there was any modification of attrs.